# How to remove hover properties with css

Tags: html, css, hover

I have the following problem:

I am trying to make to menus, one for desktop, and one for mobile/small screens.

The problem I have, is that in the media tag for mobile and small screens, i don't know how to reset the hover Properties.

What i'm trying

```
.menu-item:hover {
  // lots of properties
}
@media for mobile and small screens {
  .menu-item:hover {
    // make :hover empty again/unset :hover
  }
}
```

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't remove properties based on them being set in another ruleset.

You can either:

- [Reset **every** property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/all) with `all: initial`
- Override **each** property set in the previous hover **explicitly**
- Wrap the previous hover in it's own `@media` rule so it only applies on larger screens (or window sizes).

Comment: Thanks, than I will use a media tag for larger screens.